# Error during template compile of module. Could not resolve component relative to [object Object]

Tags: angular, docker, npm, dockerfile, devops

I have the project folder structure as.

[image: Project structure]

The **cable** folder has component in it's path, `/folder1/folder2/dialogs/changes-dialog/details-wizard/add-packages/new-package-definition/package-selection/package-selection.component`

and package.json is

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.7.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json --sourceMap=false",
    "build": "ng build --aot --configuration production",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.1.4",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "~8.1.4",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.4",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^3.0.0",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-angular": "^3.6.1",
    "ag-grid": "^17.1.1",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^17.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "core-js": "^3.3.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "mydaterangepicker": "4.2.1",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^5.3.4",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.6.0",
    "ngx-lightbox": "^2.0.0",
    "ngx-moment": "^5.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.4",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "primeng": "5.2.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "~6.5.2",
    "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.8",
    "tinymce": "^4.9.11",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "ts-md5": "^1.2.9",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.4.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.6",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.108",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~5.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.20.1",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3",
    "webdriver-manager": "12.0.6"
  }
}
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
# Step 1: Build the app in image 'builder'
FROM node:10.23.0 AS builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

# Step 2: Use build output from 'builder'
FROM nginx:1.13

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist/my-project /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

When I run [npm run build] command, it works fine and creates dist folder. But when I run the same command using Dockerfile, it fails with below error.

```
PS D:\projects\myproject> docker build -t myproject/ui .
[+] Building 242.5s (12/14)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                         0.6s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                                          0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                            0.8s 
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                                                                             0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx:1.13                                                                                                5.5s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:10.23.0                                                                                              3.9s 
 => [builder 1/6] FROM docker.io/library/node:10.23.0@sha256:57e6dc91af813f8d1c7e05d60871eca8cba67b1e120c1ae7192315114cf68de2                        0.0s 
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                            0.9s 
 => => transferring context: 102.96kB                                                                                                                        0.5s 
 => CACHED [stage-1 1/3] FROM docker.io/library/nginx:1.13@sha256:b1d09e9718890e6ebbbd2bc319ef1611559e30ce1b6f56b2e3b479d9da51dc35                           0.0s 
 => CACHED [builder 2/6] WORKDIR /usr/src/app                                                                                                        0.0s 
 => CACHED [builder 3/6] COPY package.json ./                                                                                                        0.0s 
 => [builder 4/6] RUN npm install                                                                                                                  165.5s 
 => [builder 5/6] COPY . .                                                                                                                           7.2s 
 => ERROR [builder 6/6] RUN npm run build                                                                                                           61.5s 
------
 > [builder 6/6] RUN npm run build:
#12 8.157 
#12 8.157 > my-project@1.7.0 build /usr/src/app
#12 8.157 > ng build configuration --production
#12 8.157
#12 60.40
#12 60.40 ERROR in app/modules/cable/cable.module.ts:59:57 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../components/cable/folder1/folder2/dialogs/changes-dialog/details-wizard/add-packages/new-package-definition/package-selection/package-selection.component'.     
#12 60.40
#12 60.40 59 import {PackageSelectionComponent } from '../../components/cable/folder1/folder2/dialogs/changes-dialog/details-wizard/add-packages/new-package-definition/package-selection/package-selection.component ';
#12 60.40                                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

#14 74.16 ERROR in app/modules/cable/cable.module.ts(129,5): Error during template compile of 'CableModule'
#14 74.16   

Could not 
resolve ../../components/cable/folder1/folder2/dialogs/changes-dialog/details-wizard
/add-packages/new-package-definition/package-selection/package-selection.component relative to [object Object]..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the error occurs due to docker engine version issue. I was using latest and switched to older version, 18.03.1-ce-win65 and the error is fixed.